# Update not working in specific situation

Tags: gun

I am fetching a list of favourite skills for a user.
(userTable)->(user)->(favourite_skill)->(skills)

```
gun.get('userTable')
   .get(user.pk)
   .get('favorite_skill')
   .map()
   .on(
     (skill, pk) => {
       cb(skill, pk)
     }
   )
```

After editing one of those skills and updating, nothing happens.
The data remains the same on the gun server as well.

```
gun.get('skillTable').get(skill.pk).put(skill)
```

All works well when I fetch a complete skill list like this:

```
gun.get('skillTable').map().on(....)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I've been swamped with meetings in SF. Okay, just to clarify the question... the `skill.pk` skill is the same as the one added to the `user.pk`'s favorite_skill list? AND, you are saying, there appears to be a bug that when the skill.pk is updated, you do not get notified from the user side? That is how I am understanding the question so far, if so, I'll double check it with a test and get back to you, @jingle .

Comment: Yes, the skills are all the same. Only difference is the way you fetch them. The favorite list uses an extra relation node to get to the skillTable, the other maps directly to the skillTable. (side note: this might also be related to something else. I noticed that on() listeners don't work anymore after calling .off()

Comment: Yes, `.off()` has 0 tests on it right now, so assume that it is basically broken (although code with it as an API target). It is very possible that `.off()` is causing the issue (I've had somebody else mention this too). Would you mind commenting out those lines and seeing if the original issue persists? Thanks so much!

Comment: I tried to reproduce this without any luck. The whole update mechanism works ok, but I think if anything was causing trouble it would have been .off()
I did discover something else with ev.off() that's reproducable. I will post that in another SO question since it's off this topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385871/ev-off-seems-to-kill-listeners-when-switching-between-2-map-calls

Comment: thanks, super appreciate it! So sounds like we are "good" for now with the updates, right? And then I'll check into the other link you just posted to deal with that.