# ev.off() seems to kill listeners when switching between 2 map() calls

Tags: gun

I have list with a filter that toggles between "all" and "favorites".
This works OK. However, when I activate the outcommented ev.off() in both methods, a toggle from one filter to the other will not produce results anymore.
Both lists will stay empty from that point on.
(btw: since ev.off() is still experimental, I'm ok for now, not using it. Maybe this info might help for future release)

1.subscribe() method that calls the relevant list methods

```
export const subscribe          = (payload, cb) => {
const filter = payload.filter
const user   = payload.user
switch (filter) {
  case 'all' :
    subscribeAllSkills(cb)
    break
  case 'favorites' :
    subscribeFavoriteSkills(user, cb)
    break
    ...
  }
}
```

2.subscribeAllSkills()

```
const subscribeAllSkills        = (cb) => {
  gun.get('skill')
     .map()
     .on(
       (skill, pk, ctx, ev) => {
           //ev.off()
           cb(skill, pk)
       }
     )
}
```

3.

```
const subscribeFavoriteSkills   = (user, cb) => {
  gun.get('user')
   .get(user.pk)
   .get('favorite_skill')
   .map()
   .on(
     (skill, pk, ctx, ev) => {
       //ev.off()
       cb(skill, pk)
     }
   )
}
```

Comment: Hmm, @Jingle I'm going to have to follow up with you more / later on this. What is your GitHub account?